# Django NameError: request is not defined in class based view

Tags: python, html, django, search

I am trying to add search functionality into my website. But I cannot seem to find a video that is using class based views.

Views:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = Post
    # queryset = Post.objects.filter(live=True)
    template_name = "public/index.html"

    def get_queryset(self):

        query = request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(title_icontains=query)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['queryset'] = Post.objects.filter(live=True)
        context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

HTML:

```
<form method='GET' action=''>
    <p class="text-muted">Keywords:</p>
    <input type="text" name='q' class="homebanner-search" placeholder="Enter your keywords">
    <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

When I try and run the server I get a 'NameError: name 'request' is not defined.

I feel like there are some more things I need to add but I am not sure what else I need to do to get this working.

Comment: inside a class based view is  self.request